# Crud opeartion in oracle tables with temporal nature

Tags: oracle, database-design, temporal-tables

I am implementing api to insert, update and delete data in oracle table. Table has valid_from and Valid_to (temporal nature) columns. There will be no hard delete in the table. Records will only be inserted in case of save/update/delete. only valid_to date will get populated every time.
I have 2 tables, say Client and Contact.

```
Client(table)                  
Id(sequence),      
Name,
Link_Id,  
Valid_from,
valid_to  


Contact(table)                
Id(sequence),   
ClientId (Foreign key)   ,
Name,
Link_Id,
Valid_from,
valid_to
```

what would be better approach to save clientId as foreign key in contact table or shall i store the association in a link table , something like

```
Client_contact_link (table)                 
Id(sequence),      
ClientId(FK),
ContactId(FK),
Valid_from,
valid_to
```

Can anyone share their experience of storing and reading data in table with valid_from and valid_to columns.
what i am looking for is a way to store these data via an api and read information via api.
Please let me know if any additional details are required.
Thanks in advance.